# Looking for a tool to create Flowchart from Delphi Source

Tags: programming, workflow

I have to work on some old and procedure oriented Sources. No Classes, just procedures :-/ 
Sometimes a procedure has >500 LoC, I am looking for a tool which helps to visualize the structure of the procedures. 
I already tried Google to find FlowChart or Nassi-Shneiderman Diagrams, which can process Delphi / Pascal Code, but did not find a good looking tool.

So the question is, can anybody recommend a well working tool? Can be commercial or free.

Comment: I don't knwo about flowcharts, but with alittle effort, you can generate Doxygen output, which will include call trees. Generally, the first thign that I do when given new software is to run it through Doxygen

Comment: And maybe subsequently use Moritz